# How can I create a global object in jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I use object `o` outside the jQuery plugin scope? I have the following snippet:

```
  var o ={};

(function ($) {
$.fn.extend({

    gridView: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            grid :{
                renderTo : '#container', 
            },
            gridHeader: {
            ************
            ***********

        };


        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            o = options; // i was expecting this step to fill the object 
            var obj = $(this);

            if( o.search.enabled){$(o.grid.renderTo).
         append('<div class="headerSearch">
     <input name="tbSearch" type="text" onchange="" onkeypress="do_this();" 
     id="tbSearch"><img src="'+ o.search.imgUrl +'" alt="Search"></div>')


          })(jQuery);
       console.log(o) ; // this gives me an empty object
```

My other Question is, how and where you can create a function the can be called `onkeypress` 
so this `do_this();` function can also see the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense, and can't work. Your jQuery code is invoked (presumably) at some later time via a `$("selector").gridView()` and *that* is when your plugin executes. Until then, nothing inside your `gridView: function` has run, and the value of `o` hasn't been modified when your code reaches `console.log(o)`.

If you want to persist some data tied to an element, you should use `$.data` to get and set data attributes on the element your plugin is being bound to. The section on Data in the [jQuery Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Data) page will be very useful.

Comment: i understood the part of the object but how can i fix the other issue ...Thanks

Comment: What other issue? Your second question isn't very clear -- where is the `do_this()` function?